# CSS responsive design using em for the layout

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, font-size

I have to design a (responsive) website, using only HTML5, CSS3, elastic design, and em as unit measurement. I dont know how to apply em on the width and height properties to make the margins of the main wrapper (i.e. div #page) equal on all sides in relation to the actual screen size.

I have tried the width and height properties with different em-values, but that leads to the margins not being equal. I have tried to find some sort of conversion between em and %, but since em is based on font size it's always the percentage of the font size. I have also tried to instead apply the position property to other containers and elements inside #page.

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <header>
            <nav></nav>
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
        </div>
        <aside></aside>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>


#page {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 1em;
}
```

I want to be able to only use em as measurement unit and have the margins of #page equal in relation to the actual screen size, but the width either becomes longer than the screen size, or the right margin is not equal to the other margins.

Here is a link to JSFiddle with my entire code:
https://jsfiddle.net/binaryglot/8dkn96g0/

Comment: _“I want to be able to only use em as measurement unit and have the margins of #page equal in relation to the actual screen size”_ - `em` is not relative to the screen size to begin with. I am not able to make sense of what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: I realize now that I was not clear enough, sorry about that! What I basically want is to use em for the width and height attributes (e.g. width: Xem), and still achieve the same results as if using percentage for the width and height attricutes.

Answer (score 0):

you can just using margin:0em auto for making the div page stay on the center. But unfortunately you can't make teh height on the center. Here the fiddle for making width and stay on center.

```
#page {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 1em;
  margin:0em auto;
  bottom: 1em;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd4fw1x5/)

You can adjust the height using padding--but you can't make it responsive for the height... so far i know.

Comment: I realize now that I was not clear enough, sorry about that! What I basically want is to use em for the width and height attributes (e.g. width: Xem), and still achieve the same results as if using percentage for the width and height attricutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #page {
    position: fixed;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

Using combination of `fixed position` and `auto margin` did the trick. Hope this helps!